# Get regular differential equation from a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of differential equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}_1 = 2t(x_1+x_2+t^2) \\ 
\dot{x}_2 = t(x_1^2-t^4-2t^2-1)+x_2^2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The way to do it is to get**one** regular (easily solvable) differential equation from this **system**.
Please, provide any ideas how to do it.

Comment: @LutzL That was my mistake. I’ve fixed it

Comment: Why do you suspect that such a radical simplification of your system exists? The system is non-trivially coupled, non-linear and non-autonomous. In general it is not possible to reduce this to one dimension.

Comment: @LutzL Frankly speaking, it just **should** exist

Comment: Only if there is some constructive reason for it, like a physical symmetry. (I mean both that a one-dimensional reduction exists and that the resulting ODE is simple to solve.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force it, isolate $x_2$ from the first equation and insert it and its derivative in the second equation.
\begin{align}
x_2&=\frac{\dot x_1}{2t}-x_1-t^2\\[1.5em]
\dot x_2&=\frac{\ddot x_1}{2t}-\frac{\dot x_1}{2t^2}-\dot x_1-2t\\
&=t(x_1^2−t^4−2t^2−1)+\left(\frac{\dot x_1}{2t}-x_1-t^2\right)^2
\end{align}
The last equality is a second order ODE in $x_1$ only, however I would not call that "simple".