# Find integrable combination for solving system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}_1 = 2t(x_1+t^2) \\ 
\dot{x}_2 = t(x_1^2-t^4-2t^2-1)+x_2^2 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x_1(1)=-2 \\ 
x_2(1) = -1 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

the way this system should be solved is to find an **integrable combination** [there is the description](http://faculty.uml.edu/Dimitris_Christodoulou/Teaching/documents/handbook_DE.pdf) (page 349 of pdf document).

I've already tried multiplying the first equation by $x_1$, the second one by $x_2$ then adding first to second so I got nothing solvable.

Also I tried multiplying the first by $x_2$, the second by $x_1$, also adding first to second so I got also nothing.

Could you please provide some **integrating combinations**.

Comment: How far did you get with my suggestion in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246458/115115 to your similar question?

Comment: @LutzL there was a mistake in previous question: in the first equation there is no $x_2$

Comment: The link that you provide to the large document only gives the general description of the method and some trivial examples. You still have not provided any reason why you expect such an integrable combination to exist. For most systems there will exist none. Even for systems where such a combination exists, even a slight modification in the coefficients will destroy this property.

Comment: You already got a first integral in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253954/115115 by solving the first equation. Then the second is a Riccati equation, where in general you also do not get a symbolic solution.

Comment: @LutzL I see your point, but the combination exists just because the task was to salve the system using it

Comment: @ЕгорПономарёв: I am confused, you can just solve the first equation and then substitute into the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We solve first equation (it's independent of the second, Bernoulli equation) and get:

$$x_1(t)=c_1e^{t^2}-t^2-1$$

2. Then we substitute $x_1(1)=-2$ and get $c_1= 0$ hence: $$x_1(t)=-t^2-1$$
3. Substitute $x_1(t)$ to the second equation and get $$\dot{x}_2(t)=x_2^2$$
4. We solve this equation so we have: $$x_2(t)=-\frac{1}{t+c_2}$$
5. Finally we substitute the $x_2(1)=-1$ and get the answer: $$x_2(t)=\frac{-1}{t}$$